Wordpress blog on main domain. Github pages on subdomain
I have a wordpress site that my boss has setup
example-project.com.
for every team that wants to showcase their version of that project he created a subdomain for them;
`teama.example-project.com`,
`teamb.example-project.com`,
`teamc.example-project.com`, etc.

there is already an opensource subdomain that showcases all the parts of the project they give people to use freely;
`open-source.example-project.com`.

but now he wants me to put that subdomain on github.
ive created a new jekyll static site on github, is it possible to link that to the already existing url
I saw this video on how to link wordpress sites to github but it is for the root site not a subdomain.

you need to configure that domain's DNS server to point the subdomain to github. see https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages
